# How do I add a method to the table type?

Tags: lua, metaprogramming

How do I add a method to the table type? I'm trying to write a method that searches through the values of a table. So far I have.

```
function table:contains(value)
  for _, v in ipairs(self) do
    if v == value then return true end
  end
  return false
end
```

Yet when I try to do the following.

```
t = {'four', 'five', 'six'}
t:contains('five')
```

I get the error.

```
stdin:1: attempt to call method 'contains' (a nil value)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that `table.contains(t, 'five')` does work. So the question comes down to: What is the difference between `instance:method(...)` and `type.method(instance, ...)`, which was also puzzling me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33052241/1804173).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no single metatable for all *tables*. Unlike strings and numbers, each table has its own individual metatable.

Just make a free function instead of a "member" function for these kinds of things. Not everything needs to be all OOP with `:` and such.

Answer (score 9):

As was said by others, your `t` is a simple table, it contains only the following key-value pairs: `[1]='four'`, `[2]='five'`, `[3]='six'`.

If you want to "extend" the `t` to be able to access functions from the `table` module, you have to set a metatable with `__index` pointing to the `table` module. I use the following function to access it easily:

```
function T(t)
    return setmetatable(t, {__index = table})
end
```

You can then use it as follows (thanks to syntax sugar no parentheses needed):

```
t = T{'four', 'five', 'six'}
t:insert('seven')
print(t:contains('seven')) --> true
```

Answer (score 3):

You've added a method to the `table` library but you haven't given any metatable to table `t`. There is no automatic connection between `table` and `t`.