# Weird behavior of syntax sugar(colon) in Lua

Tags: function, lua, lua-table, syntactic-sugar

```
function string.test(s)
    print('test')
end

a = 'bar'
string.test(a)
a:test()
```

All is fine until next example.

```
function table.test(s)
    print('test')
end

b = {1,2,3}
table.test(b)
b:test() -- error
```

Why do I getting the error?
It was working fine at strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a method to the table type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778812/how-do-i-add-a-method-to-the-table-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While daurn answers your question nicely, allow be to explain why this is.

In Lua, all datatypes can have a metatable. (Although it's quite different when dealing with numbers,bools,etc. See debug.setmetatable.) This includes the string. By default this is set to index string library with __index, it is when make syntactic sugar like `print(s:sub(1,5))` (s being a string) possible.

This is NOT the same with tables. By default tables have NO metatable. You have to manually set it with setmetatable.

And to conclude my answer, enjoy this code snippet

```
debug.setmetatable(0,{__index=math})
debug.setmetatable(function()end,{__index=coroutine})
debug.setmetatable(coroutine.create(function()end), {__index=coroutine})
local function Tab(tab)
    return setmetatable(tab,{__index=table})
end
```

This basically allows you to use math functions on numbers

```
local x = 5.7
print(x:floor())
```

And do similar things with functions and threads, using coroutine functions:

```
print:create():resume()
```

Pretty hacky if you ask me

And of course, create tables and use table functions on them:

```
local x = Tab{1,2,3,4}
x:insert(5)
x:remove(1)
print(x:concat(", "))
```

I find it hard to imagine anybody who don't like cool tricks like that.

Comment: I copypasted your code and for a reason I got a error  "attempt to index local 'x' (a number value)"
I'm using Lua 5.1.4 on windows 7.

Comment: I doubt that it works in Lua 5.2. It should be `debug.setmetatable(0, { __index=math })`. (And that works on Lua 5.1 as well.)

Comment: @siffiejoe So it is. Thanks, I don't know how I pasted the wrong code. I blame iOS!

Comment: @Parki It has been fixed.

Comment: @warspyking is it possible to set a metatable to every table by defualt like in your "Tab" function?

Comment: @Parki While there's no way to detect when an anonymous table (I think you can call them that), you can set a metatable to _G and wrap it so that new tables assigned to global variables have that metatable by default. Out of curiosity though, why not be consistent and put your function in table and call it like any other... `table.test(tab)`

Comment: @warspyking improved your code a bit https://github.com/Parki0/LuaColonSuntaxSugar

Comment: @Parki Well obviously you can make a constructor function. You said by default though.

Answer (score 5):

Tables do not have a metatable by default like strings do.

Try instead:

```
function table.test(s)
    print('test')
end

b = setmetatable({1,2,3}, {__index=table})
table.test(b)
b:test() -- error
```